# Fluentd persistence and reliability

Tags: persistence, reliability, fluentd

Since fluentd does not use redis but supposedly has better built in reliability, how does that solve the problem of the instance going down before it has a chance to send the logs to elastic search? Is this something not significant enough to worry about, for example you could set the steaming of logs at a high frequency, so if you ever lose the instance, only a few lines would have no transferred over?

Answer (score 0):

Fluentd uses a buffering mechanism, once it receive a set of events they are stored either in memory or in the file system, the latest is what is used for reliability. The events are stored in chunks, then upon a certain period of time it flush the chunks to the destination. If a chunk failed, it will retry later.

You can read more about buffering in the official documentation:

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/buffer-plugin-overview